# css max-width property and outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I've got a bug when sending email and then opening them in microsoft outlook.

The bug is that Outlook doesn't support the css max-width parameters and which is used to define an image size.

I try something with conditional rendering :

```
<td class="mcnImageContent" valign="top" style="text-align: <%= @booking.trip.theme.email_client_logo_position || 'left' %>; padding-right: 9px;padding-left: 9px;padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
    <% if email_logo_url %>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="<%= @booking.present? ?
                (@booking.trip.theme.email_client_logo_zoom.to_f * 
                400.to_f).to_i.to_f : 
                ((@resource.client.try(:theme).try(:email_client_logo_zoom) || 
                1).to_f * 400.to_f).to_i.to_s %>">
                <![endif]-->
                <img alt="" src="<%= email_logo_url %>" style="max-width: <%= 
                    @booking.present? ? (@booking.trip.theme.email_client_logo_zoom.to_f 
                    * 400.to_f).to_i.to_f : 
                    ((@resource.client.try(:theme).try(:email_client_logo_zoom) || 
                    1).to_f * 400.to_f).to_i.to_s %>px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline 
                    !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;line-height: 
                    100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;height: auto !important;" 
                    class="mcnImage">
                <!--[if mso]>
            </td>
```

Can someone help me to set the correct size for the picture?

Answer (score 16):

You're absolutely right that Outlook doesn't support `max-width`. The best way to code images for HTML emails is to use the `width` attribute on the `img` tag, along with some inline styles that allow for images to be responsive by default (without you having to target w/ a class and update via a media query).

Here's the code I use for all images. The `width` attribute covers problems w/ Outlook (and a few other clients) and the inline styles work everywhere else:

```
<img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" width="600" border="0" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; min-width: 100px; width: 100%;">
```

The `min-width` property is there just to make sure that, when viewed on smaller screens, the image doesn't get too small.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the email!